# error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(int&)’

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am new in c++.  When I run my code got this error :(

> Big Sorting.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
>       Big Sorting.cpp:13:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector >::push_back(int&)’
>                v.push_back(m);
>                             ^
>       In file included from /usr/include/c++/8.1.1/vector:64,
>                        from Big Sorting.cpp:2:
>       /usr/include/c++/8.1.1/bits/stl_vector.h:1074:7: note: candidate: ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp
>   = std::__cxx11::basic_string; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::vector<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::value_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string]’
>              push_back(const value_type& __x)
>              ^~~~~~~~~
>       /usr/include/c++/8.1.1/bits/stl_vector.h:1074:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const value_type&’ {aka
>   ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string&’}
>       /usr/include/c++/8.1.1/bits/stl_vector.h:1090:7: note: candidate: ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type =
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string]’
>              push_back(value_type&& __x)
>              ^~~~~~~~~
>       /usr/include/c++/8.1.1/bits/stl_vector.h:1090:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to
>   ‘std::vector >::value_type&&’ {aka
>   ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string&&’}

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> m;
        v.push_back(m);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m` is an int. You can't put an int into a vector of strings.

Comment: Upvoted because you included the entire error message.

Comment: Btw, include `<string>`

Comment: Ah, the woes of template error messages...

Comment: Particularilly bad because The error is supprisingly bigger than your code...

Answer (score 3):

You are reading `int` variable `m` and trying to put it into a vector of strings. You should use `std::vector<int>` instead.

**Bottom line**: your code needs **only one change**, most reasonable one would be to change `std::vector<std::string>` to `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Or convert the `int` to a `std::string` before pushing it

Comment: Or declare `m` as a `std::string`, which may have been the author's intent.

Comment: I have tried to convert a string to int then I got this error     " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  stoi
Aborted (core dumped)"

Comment: @JeJo I Edited My Code as your advice but still going error here take a look on my code <code>#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string m;
    int n;
    size_t s;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> m;
        v.push_back(std::stoi(m, &s));
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
</code>

Comment: @Riajulkashem All you needed to do was change `int m` to `string m`. Only then can you do `push_back(m)`